# Use ajax/jquery to insert data to databse and refresh a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am sort of working on a chat, and I've done what's needed in PHP but to make it look better I would like to be able to insert my message into the database without reloading the page, and (if possible) when the message is posted I want the while loop to refresh all messages on the page, and again without reloading the page.

```
if(isset($_POST["shoutbox_submit"])) {
    $shoutbox_message = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST["shoutbox_text"]);
    if (strlen($shoutbox_message) > 600) {
        echo "<div class='errormsg'>Sorry, your message is too long.</div>";
    } elseif (strlen($shoutbox_message) <= 600) {
        $insertsb = $DB->query("INSERT INTO db_shoutbox (poster, message, date) VALUES('".$dbuser."', '".$shoutbox_message."', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')");
    }
}
```

And my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <textarea name="shoutbox_text" class="newscommentstyle" placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Post" name="shoutbox_submit" class="newscommentsubmit" style="width: 100%;">
</form>
<br style="clear:both;">
```

And the while loop to show the messages:

```
$getsbcomment = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM db_shoutbox ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25");
while ($fetchsb = $getsbcomment->fetch_array()) {
    echo $fetchsb["message"];
}
```

Never quite worked with sort of stuff I want to do before, so I will appreciate all help I can get.

Comment: I suggest that you make an attempt, then show us what you tried and where you got stuck. For reference, see [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [its examples](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples).

Comment: Thanks for the links, will do

Comment: I am not very sure that you need a while loop, thus in most cases it indicates poor design and/or bad implementation. You need to look at ajax and keep in mind that PHP is strictly on the server, it does not keep persistent connection and can't push any info to the client, without refreshing the page. You could look in to long pooling with ajax